# change python list (mutable object in general) values with something like map, but not returning new object

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Python map function works both on mutables and immutables, it returns new iterable object(for python 3.x).

However I would like only to change the values (of a mutable object eg. list, np.ndarray), in the nice and consistent manner similar to the map().

Given following function:

```
def perturbation_bin(x, prob):
    '''
    Perturbation operation for binary representation. Decide independently for each bit, if it will be inverted or not.

    :param x: binary chromosome
    :param prob: bit inversion probability
    :return: None
    '''
    assert x.__class__ == np.ndarray, '\nBinary chromosome must np.ndarray.'
    assert x.dtype == np.int8, '\nBinary chromosome np.dtype must be np.int8.'
    x[np.where(np.random.rand(len(x)) <= prob)] += 1
    map(partial(np.mod, x2=2), x)
```

This code for each 'bit' (np.int8) randomly adds or adds not +1, changing the numpy ndarray object passed to the function.
However in the next step I would like to apply modulo to all elements of this np.ndarray.
As the code is written now, it only creates new map object inside the function.

Does such map-like function in python exist, not returning new object but altering the mutable object values instead?

Thank you

Comment: Note that this line `x[np.where(np.random.rand(len(x)) <= prob)] += 1` is also creating a temporary object the size of your input with `np.random.rand(len(x)) <= prob)` and an additional potentially large -- but of unknown size because of the randomness -- object with `np.where()`. If you are memory limited I would seek into memory optimize also that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. But you could easily make one, as long as the object you are willing to modify is a Sequence (specifically, you would need `__len__`, `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to be defined):

```
def apply(obj, func):
    n = len(obj)
    for i in range(n):
        obj[i] = func(obj[i])
    return obj  # or None
```

This is not going to be the fastest execution around, but it may be accelerated with Numba (provided that you work with suitable objects, e.g. Numpy arrays).

---

As for your specific problem you can replace:

```
map(partial(np.mod, x2=2), x)
```

with:

```
apply(x, lambda x: x % 2)
```

or, with a much more performant:

```
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def apply_nb(obj, func):
    n = len(obj)
    for i in range(n):
        obj[i] = func(obj[i])
    return obj


@nb.njit
def mod2_nb(x):
    return x % 2


apply_nb(x, mod2_nb)
```

Note that many NumPy functions, like [`np.mod()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html) also support a `out` parameter:

```
np.mod(x, 2, out=x)
```

which will perform the operation in-place.

---

Timewise, the Numba-based operation seems to have an edge:

```
import numpy as np


x = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000)


%timeit X = x.copy(); np.mod(X, 2, out=X)                                                                       
# 9.47 µs ± 22.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit X = x.copy(); apply_nb(X, mod2_nb)                                                                      
# 7.51 µs ± 173 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit X = x.copy(); apply(X, lambda x: x % 2)                                                                 
# 350 µs ± 4.58 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems that for the case with np.ndarray and np.mod() the 'out' parameter' solves the problem without third site packages (not counting the numpy), even tho slower than using numba package. Does anybody know how is the use of numpy out parameter internally implemented?

Comment: Feast your eyes on NumPy's source code: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/aa61d14bf4aee3ec16e98695b6996ee7e22858ff/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h.src